# SMSG Calculus Usage?

Tags: secondary-education, calculus, textbooks, history, new-math

Did anyone out there have experience with SMSG's Calculus text? Our school system  (Amherst, MA) used SMSG texts from my 6th grade class onward. But for HS Calculus (1969) we didn't use the two-part SMSG Calculus text (copyright 1966). Was there some issue with it? Too hard, too "abstract" etc.?

Comment: In what era were you in this system/using these texts?

Comment: Question says his hs calc class was in 1969.

Comment: I don't have any information about usage & adoption, but in case you don't have them, the texts themselves are available at http://bit.ly/SMSG-archive.